# Is a well-ordered set always countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $A$ is a well-ordered set. We can find $a_{0} = \min{A}$. Then, if $A \setminus \left\{a_{0}\right\} \neq \emptyset$, we can find $a_{1} = \min{\left(A \setminus \left\{a_{0}\right\}\right)}$, etc. Intuitively, this seems to be a counting process. Then my hypothesis is, every well-ordered set is countable. Is this a valid guess? In my understanding, if it is valid, then for finite well-ordered sets, we can use mathematical induction to prove it. Then what about infinite cases?

Comment: It's not a bad guess, but it turns out that every set can be well-ordered (this fact is equivalent to the axiom of choice).

Comment: No. Actually, given the axiom of choice any nonempty set can be well ordered. And even without the axiom of choice there are uncountable sets.

Comment: What if no axiom of choice?

Comment: Even without the axiom of choice, any ordinal is well ordered.

Comment: @Mark: Well, that doesn't help much unless you know there are uncountable ordinals.

Comment: [Hartogs' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs_number) doesn't require the axiom of choice, and proves that for every set $A$ there is a well-ordered set  $\alpha$ (indeed an ordinal) for which there is no injection from $\alpha$ to $A$.  If you take $A$ to be a countable set then the resulting $\alpha$ is necessarily uncountable.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge Do you need the axiom of choice for that though?

Comment: @Mark: For Hartogs' theorem?  As I said, no you don't.  For the existence of uncountable ordinals?  No, since it follows from Hartogs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To clarify exactly what's going on, your argument shows there is a countably infinite subset of any infinite well-ordered ordinal. The reason it doesn't show any well-ordered set is countable is that there's no reason your process should exhaust the set A. If we consider the set $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$, where we add a point larger than any natural, we can check this is still a well-ordered set. But the process you describe will never "count" the point at infinity. Of course this set is still countable, but the idea is instead of adding 1 point we can add uncountably many (a priori it's not clear how to order these points, this is just supposed to show why we can get uncountable ordinals).

Comment: This seems to be a more detailed answer. The fact that we can count forever doesn't mean it is countable.

Answer (score 6):

Every ordinal is well-ordered by $\in$. Ordinals are arbitrarily large. All the axiom of choice adds is that all sets biject with an ordinal, thereby being well-orderable. Even proper classes can be well-orderable; the class of ordinals is well-ordered by $\in$.

Comment: Although I have not read ordinals, thanks for your answer. It makes me aware of what ordinals are about.

Comment: @ZiqiFan [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Well-ordered_sets) would make for good reading. The axiom of choice biject sets with ordinals because if $f$ is a choice function on $\mathcal{P}(X)\setminus\emptyset$ and $\iota(\alpha)$ is defined for ordinals $\alpha$ as $f(X\setminus\{\iota(\beta)|\beta\in\alpha\})$ then, since $\iota$'s domain can't be the class of all ordinals [because it's not a set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burali-Forti_paradox), there is a least $\alpha$ for which $\iota(\alpha)$ is undefined, i.e. $\{\iota(\beta)|\beta\in\alpha\})=X$.

Comment: @ZiqiFan Well-ordering of all sets [also implies AC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_theorem#Proof_of_AC).

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to point out why your intuitive argument is wrong. Your sequence starts with the smallest element of $A$, then moves to the next smallest element of $A$ - the *successor* of $a_0$. By induction (as per the Peano axioms), this process will eventually reach every natural number if we apply it to $\mathbb N$. By the way, it's typical to write $\omega = \mathbb N$ when referring to it as an ordinal. The thing is, your process being exhaustive would require that every element of $A$ other than the smallest one is a successor of some other element. I'll give you an example of a well ordered set where this does not hold.

As I said, we have $\omega = \mathbb N$. Let's define a new set, called $\omega + 1$, as $\omega \cup \{\infty\}$, where $\infty$ is just some symbol not in $\omega$. We'll keep the ordering on $\omega$ and assert that $\infty$ is strictly bigger than every element of $\omega$. This makes $\omega + 1$ into a well ordered set. Essentially, if a nonempty subset contains $\infty$ then its minimum is either $\infty$ itself or removing $\infty$ does not change the minimum. Now, if you tried to apply this process to $\omega + 1$, you would get $a_0 = 0$, $a_1 = 1$,... , $a_n = n$. However, you would never reach $\infty$ as there is no $n \in \omega$ whose successor is $\infty$.

I'd like to point you to the notion of transfinite induction, however. This is a method that allows you to make inductive arguments on any well ordered set, as you have tried to do. The difference is that you have to account for these $\infty$ esque elements which are not a successor of anything (called limit ordinals). If you can prove a property $P$ holds for all limit ordinals in $A$ and that $P(\alpha) \implies P(succ(\alpha))$ then $P$ holds for all $\alpha$ in $A$.

I'd also like to point out that the more standard notation is $\omega + 1 = \omega \cup \{\omega\}$. This definition of the successor ordinal allows for a very clean theory. Here, we have that $\omega \in \omega + 1$ is a limit ordinal, so doing induction on $\omega + 1$ requires treating this case specially.