$\mathbb{R}$ can be well ordered
I am trying to wrap my head around the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ can be well ordered (under some unknown order relation). Since the well ordering theorem says that every non-empty subset of a set has a least element, and since $\mathbb{R}$ is a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ it follows that we can identify the least element of $\mathbb{R}$ (under some hitherto unknown order), say $l$ and, assign to it the number 1. Then we can find the least element of $\mathbb{R}-\{l\}$ and assign it the next integer and so on. Clearly this process won't cover the entirety of $\mathbb{R}$ as that wouldn't imply that $\mathbb{R}$ is countable. Do I have this right?

Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/6501/42969

That process wouldn't cover the entirety of $\mathbb R$, essentially because you stopped too early. If you want to "index" a well-ordering of $\mathbb R$, then you would have to use all of the ordinals that appear in $\mathfrak c$. Roughly speaking, to get a well-ordering of $\mathbb R$ you need to pick a real $x_0\in\mathbb R$, a real $x_1\in\mathbb R\setminus{x_0}$, a real $x_2\in\mathbb R\setminus{x_0,x_1}$, ...., and then a real $x_{\omega}\in\mathbb R\setminus{x_n\mid n\in\mathbb N}$, and so on. This goes on for a long time.

Yes, you have it right. What you end up with is an initial segment of $\mathbb{R}$ under the well-ordering, isomorhpic to the positive integers.

@Joe I think I get what you're saying but I also think that you formulation is not allowed under recursive definition but only under transfinite recursion which is out of my depth.

There have been several questions on this very topic, unfortunately, I think they are all deleted (since they were asked by a well-known crank as a platform for his soapboxing), so I can't quite find a duplicate. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4024749/is-a-well-ordered-set-always-countable is probably the closest I can find today.

Yes, you need to use transfinite recursion (among other things) to formalise this argument, and unfortunately the gap between the informal argument I gave and the formalised argument is rather large. Incidentally, I wrote something about this yesterday.
